# 'NewConnectionError' with Snowflake connector for python and fetch_pandas_batches()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm returning ~190m records from a Snowflake database, via `fetch_pandas_batches()` and the Snowflake connector for python. I am experiencing dozens of the following errors while fetching  some batches of records;

```
WARNING - Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object
at 0x7fe5b8bb1e50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')'...
```

The code is extremely simple;

```
connection = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user = 'my_uid',
        password = 'my_pwd',
        account = 'my_account',
        role = 'my_role',
        authenticator = 'my_url',
        warehouse = 'my_warehouse')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "my_sql_query"

sql_cursor.execute(query)
for df in sql_cursor.fetch_pandas_batches():
    print(len(df))
```

- The errors always occur as the last N batches are being called, never at the start of the fetch
- All expected records are returned successfully
- Queries that return fewer rows, don't throw the error

Any suggestions as to what is going on here?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you trying to pull 190m records out of Snowflake using Pandas?

Comment: @NickW: I'm running some data quality analysis on the records and similar to chunksize attribute, fetch_pandas_batches() allows me to pull smaller datasets at a time that fit into memory and allow me to run the analysis, etc.

Comment: Just to clarify, is "my_sql_query" your DQ analytical queries or is it the equivalent of "select * from..." and is pulling raw data from Snowflake against which you are subsequently running DQ queries? If it is the 2nd scenario then this doesn't seem like a good idea. Why not use pandas to run analytical queries directly on Snowflake (and process the results with pandas if necessary) as that is the type of workload Snowflake was designed to handle?

Comment: When you write "Queries that return fewer rows..." how many rows? There is a different path to download data in Snowflake depending on the result set size.